# To remove Green cross errors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS 2.8.3.After dissolving a shapefile i will check for geometry validity there it shows many green cross errors( two nodes overlap at a time which results in that green crosses) i got some 200 crosses like this. How do i can remove this automatically because doing it manually consume lot of man hours

Answer (score 3):

Take a look the the `Remove Duplicate Vertices` tool in the geoprocessing Toolbox. [image]
Note, I am using QGIS 3, and you should too, QGIS 2 is not going to be around much more.

Comment: QGIS 2.18 is the current long term release version.

Comment: @csk The final QGIS 2 release is set for January 2019. Later this month QGIS 3.4 will be released which will become the new LTR.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html